# Java: Make a gridbased boardgame

Tags: java, grid, imageview, javafx

I need to make a boardgame where the user can select an image and use it as a board. The image part is easy, though I need help with how to make equal sized grids based upon user input. For example there could be a 10x10 grid or a 50x50.

My current approach is by having a StackPane that has a GridPane over a ImageView. All of this is inside a ScollPane so that the image can be as big as possible.

Are there any other better ways  of doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use a [GridPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html) for your board.

---

I used the same method for my [Tic-Tac-Toe game](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/5115901) - it worked fine.

```
class BoardSkin extends GridPane {
  BoardSkin(Board board) {
    getStyleClass().add("board");

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        add(board.getSquare(i, j).getSkin(), i, j);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

You can use a [StackPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html) with an [ImageView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html) layered behind your board grid squares as you mention in your question, but it's not strictly necessary.

Instead, I'd use some updated css from the tic-tac-toe game linked earlier.  To get the board image layered behind the grid squares, set the board image as a background image for the grid.

```
.board {
  -fx-hgap: 10px;
  -fx-vgap: 10px;
  -fx-background-image: url('http://www.woodge.com/books/maps/map_Narnia.jpg');
  -fx-background-size: cover;
  -fx-background-position: center;
}

.square {
  -fx-padding: 10px;
  -fx-background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.4);
}
```

[image: boardgamebackground]

Comment: Thanks. Your reply helped me quite a bit.